# Compiling a c++ program with g++ using libcrypto in Debian 7.0

Tags: c++, g++

I have a problem with a program when trying to comile it using `g++`. This is the command :

```
root@server1:/home# g++ -o ssh2main ssh2main.cpp ssh2connect.cpp -static -lssh2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -lcrypto -ldl -lz -Wno-write-strings;
```

And this is the output that i get :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already run `apt-get libcrypt*` and i see that it is installed.

```
root@server1: locate crypt
/lib/libcryptsetup.so.4
/lib/libcryptsetup.so.4.2.0

...

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20.0.3

...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/cryptsetup-bin.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cryptsetup-bin.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcryptsetup4.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcryptsetup4.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcryptsetup4.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcryptsetup4.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcryptsetup4.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcryptsetup4.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt11:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt11:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt11:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt11:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt11:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt11:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcrypt20:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libk5crypto3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libk5crypto3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libk5crypto3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libk5crypto3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libk5crypto3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libk5crypto3:amd64.symbols
```

The thing is that on `CentOS 5.5, 5.7` it works with no problem. What am i doing wrong? How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is `libcrypt` of GNU, not `libcrypto`

Install `libssl-dev` package. I am assuming package name in ubuntu and debian are same. otherwise, you need to install corresponding `ssl-dev` pkg for you platform

Comment: If this is what you are looking, Please mark this as answer

Comment: I get errors :
root@server1-2:/home/ # apt-get install libssl-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libssl-devel .... where do i look for how to install libcrypto for Debian? it seems that for CentOS everything is ok ...

Comment: Oops, my mistake, It package name should be `libssl-dev`, edited accrodingly in answer too.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

> I already run apt-get libcrypt* and i see that it is installed.

try `-lcrypt`

I also noticed that you do not have a -L for the link path directory. Is the correct path in your default setting?

Comment: i did `-lcrypt` instead of `-lcrypto` and i get a lot of errors http://pastebin.com/RQ2VgHpi . Also i get same errors when i try to compile without `-lcrypto`

Comment: @Damian Did you have the correct default setting or the correct value for -L

Comment: `-L` is used when i need to specify a path to that library right? if so what should i put there? i have `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.4
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.4.6.0
/usr/lib/libcrypto++.so
/usr/lib/libcrypto++.so.9
/usr/lib/libcrypto++.so.9.0.0
/usr/lib/libcryptopp.so
/usr/lib/libcryptopp.so.9
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libcrypto++.so.9.0.0
... so on ....
`

Comment: @Damian I do not have your setup so I cannot tell. /usr/lib should be in the default list so perhaps use an explicit -l (such as `-l crypto++` or one of the others). Alternatively add one of the other directories and -l an explicit library.

Comment: @Damian If the directory that apt-get used to install it is not in the default list, use it for the -L additionally, you may need to move it to the head of the list.